# Vue two-way data binding issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

My own vue component sends http request to receive array of objects, then I store the answer in data property, and it's fine. Now I want to bind this array to v-model, but when user will input something my array is changed too. I want to store the array for later and make it not editable, I just want to bind its value to v-model, not reference to my array. My target is to allow user to reset v-model value to array received from api. I hope you get the point and you will be able to help me.

```
<draggable v-model="myArray">
   <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id">{{element.name}}</div>
</draggable>
<button @click="addElement">New</button>
```

```
data() {
   return {
       myArray: [],
       array: []
   }
},
methods: {
   addElement() {
      myArray.push({id:1, name:'something'});
   },
   getData() {
      axios(...)
      .then(res => {
         this.array = response.data;
      });
   }
   setData() {
      this.myArray = this.array;
   }
}
```

Now if user will add new element to `myArray` it will be also inserted in `array`

Comment: Have you tried pass cloned array using `array.map`, `array.filter` or something similar?

Comment: I've updated post, now you can see the code, @Darius, yeah I've tried this, but got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Data must be cloned:

```js
new Vue({
  template: '<div>List1:<ul><li v-for="i in array1" :key="i.id">{{i.name}}</li></ul>List2:<ul><li v-for="i in array2" :key="i.id">{{i.name}}</li></ul><button @click="add">Add</button></div>',
  data: {
    array1: [{id:1, name:'Item1'},{id:2, name:'Item2'}],
    array2: []
  },
  created() {
    // clone array
    this.array2 = this.array1.map(i => Object.assign({},i))
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.array1.push({id:this.array1.length+1, name:'Item'+(this.array1.length+1)})
      this.array1[0].name = 'Item1/' + this.array1.length
    }
  }
}).$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If it is more complex array of objects, then must use some sort of deep-clone.

Comment: I've tried with `Object.create` instead of `Object.assign`, that's the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue using the JSON parse to make the to-be-copied-array loose dinamic relation with the array-to-be-created. Try the following:

```
data() {
   return {
       myArray: [],
       array: []
   }
},
methods: {
   addElement() {
      myArray.push({id:1, name:'something'});
   },
   getData() {
      axios(...)
      .then(res => {
         this.array = response.data;
      });
   }
   setData() {
      this.myArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.array)); // Here goes the trick
   }
}
```

This way every change on v-model array by the user won't be reflected on myArray since the setData() is called at least once before the user interaton.

Hope it suits you well.